# How can I copy pixel data from an unmanaged buffer to an Image on ImageSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, image, imagesharp

I have an image buffer that lives in the unmanaged heap and I want to manipulate it with ImageSharp.

Right now I'm copying the unmanaged buffer into a byte array and then calling `Image.LoadPixelData()` which copies the buffer again into the image `PixelBuffer`.

How can I do a single copy instead? My image is in `Argb32` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help from [Anton Firsov](https://twitter.com/antonfrv) on the [ImageSharp gitter](https://gitter.im/ImageSharp/General), I could do what I wanted. I needed to use `DangerousGetPinnableReferenceToPixelBuffer()`:

```
using(var image  = new Image<Argb32>(surfaceLock.Width, surfaceLock.Height))
using(var output = new MemoryStream()) {
    unsafe {
        fixed(void* buffer = &image.DangerousGetPinnableReferenceToPixelBuffer()) {
            memcpy((IntPtr)buffer, surfaceLock.Buffer, surfaceLock.SlicePitchInBytes);
        }
    }
    image.Save(output, jpegEncoder);
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, DangerousGetPinnableReferenceToPixelBuffer is gone. ImageSharp is frankly exasperating when you have to make it work with unmanaged code (read - any graphics API).

Answer (score 1):

You could create UnmanagedMemoryStream and then Image.Load(stream)) but I am not sure if it is better than what you are doing now

Comment: I don't have a LoadPixelData() that takes a Stream (I have raw image data). I tried memcopying to a DangerousGetPinnableReferenceToPixelBuffer() pinned handle, but that fails miserably (I still don't know why).

Comment: check here from bytes 
 https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/master/src/ImageSharp/Image/Image.FromBytes.cs  or here from stream https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Comment: Those try to read an image in an encoded format. I need to `LoadPixelData` as I have the sequences of bytes representing the pixels in the image.

Comment: using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("foo.jpg"))
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(stream)) if you create a stream from your data instead of the file you probably can do the same

Comment: I thank you for your help, but that does not work. If I do `var singleBlackPixel = new byte[4]; Image.Load<Argb32>(singleBlackPixel);` that obviously won't work (as `singleBlackPixel` does not have any metadata associated with it). I can make my system work by copying my unmanaged buffer into a managed byte array (which gets copied in turn by the `LoadPixelData`). I want to remove that extra copy and copy directly from the unmanaged buffer into the Image.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158343/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-pablo-montilla).

Comment: was waiting for you on chat